# TypeError during assignment to attribute reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, attr

Reading about [Assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) in the Python's docs I found this:

> If the target is an attribute reference: The primary expression in the reference is evaluated. It should yield an object with assignable attributes; if this is not the case, `TypeError` is raised. That object is then asked to assign the assigned object to the given attribute; if it cannot perform the assignment, it raises an exception (usually but not necessarily `AttributeError`).

I'm wondering how to get this `TypeError`?

**What Python's types doesn't have routine for setting attributes?**

Comment: I use python approximately 2 years, but have never encountered  such a situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This documentation line is just really out of date. It dates back to at least [Python 1.4](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref6.html#HDR2), long before type/class unification. I believe back then, trying to do something like

```
x = 1
x.foo = 3
```

would have produced a TypeError, but I wasn't writing Python back then, and I don't have a sufficiently ancient interpreter version to test it.

If you look at the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/object.c#l914) for attribute assignment dispatch, you can see that the documented check still exists:

```
if (tp->tp_setattro != NULL) {
    ...
    return ...;
}
if (tp->tp_setattr != NULL) {
    ...
    return ...;
}
Py_DECREF(name);
assert(name->ob_refcnt >= 1);
if (tp->tp_getattr == NULL && tp->tp_getattro == NULL)
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "'%.100s' object has no attributes "
                 "(%s .%U)",
                 tp->tp_name,
                 value==NULL ? "del" : "assign to",
                 name);
else
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "'%.100s' object has only read-only attributes "
                 "(%s .%U)",
                 tp->tp_name,
                 value==NULL ? "del" : "assign to",
                 name);
return -1;
```

If an object's type has no routine for setting attributes, Python raises an error, complaining about "no attributes" or "only read-only attributes" depending on whether the type has a routine for getting attributes. I believe in the early days, types like `int` would have gone down this code path. However, all types now inherit such routines from `object`, so I don't think this code path is ever taken.

There's a related code path in [`type.__setattr__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c#l3005) that raises a `TypeError` for setting attributes on types written in C. This code path is still taken, but it's not as general as what the documentation describes:

```
if (!(type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE)) {
    PyErr_Format(
        PyExc_TypeError,
        "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '%s'",
        type->tp_name);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You hint me an answer `object.some_attr` raises TypeError :)

Comment: I think that can still happen if you explicitly delete `__setattr__`. I didn't test it though.

Comment: @Kritzefitz No, no you can't `del`, if you can't assign!

Comment: I slightly modify my question, because you really revealed to me what I was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This code produces a `TypeError` and it seems like it is what the documentation describes:

```
>>> def f(): pass
...
>>> f.func_globals = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: readonly attribute
```

But is this `TypeError` really raised because the documentation says that? I sincerely doubt it. I guess `func_globals` implementation simply raises `TypeError` if you try to assign something to it.

**BTW...**

I would actually excpect the same in the next example, but it is an `AttributeError` instead:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     __slots__ = 'a',
...
>>> A().b = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'b'
```

**Update (Python 3)**

The above was in Python 2.7. In Python 3, there is no `func_globals`, so this is not applicable (you can assign anything to it).

What attributes function has in Python 3 seem to raise an `AttributeError` when it is read-only.

```
>>> f.__globals__ = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

This makes perfect sense to me. Perhaps this part of the documentation is just a relic as far as Python 3 is concerned.

Comment: It does not raise an error in my case for `f.func_globals`. I use Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to raise TypeError in your code:

```
raise TypeError
```

I suggest you read up on exceptions and exception handling in Python for more information. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html